# Выбрать тип через switch?

Tags: c#, сопоставление-с-образцом

Как на c# 7 выбирать тип через switch?
Как следующий пример будет записываться через switch?

```
var items = new object[] { 1, "tt", DateTime.UtcNow };

foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item is int)
        Console.WriteLine((int)item);
    else if (item is string)
        Console.WriteLine("'" + ((string)item).Replace("'", "''") + "'");
    else if (item is DateTime)
        Console.WriteLine("'" + ((DateTime)item).ToString("O") + "'");
}
```

Следующий вариант не работает. Выдает ошибки, что не известны переменные i, s и date:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case item is int i:
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            break;
        case item is string s:
            Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
            break;
        case item is DateTime date:
            Console.WriteLine("'" + date.ToString("O") + "'");
            break;
    }
}
```

Через if работает:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item is int i)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    else if (item is string s)
        Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
    else if (item is DateTime date)
        Console.WriteLine("'" + date.ToString("O") + "'");
}
```

Comment: Ну, C# 7 ещё вроде бы не вышел? Где вы раздобыли компилятор?

Comment: @VladD Недо-C# 7 доступен в Visual Studio 15 Preview 2 (не путать с Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: Можно и в VS2015 его подцепить. Правда, не без извращений: [LRN Quick Tip: How to Test out C# 7 Features with Roslyn](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/lrn-quick-tip-how-to-test-out-c-7-features-with-roslyn/)

Comment: @Serj-Tm: Ого! Круто, да.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case int i:
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            break;
        case string s:
            Console.WriteLine("'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
            break;
        case DateTime date:
            Console.WriteLine("'" + date.ToString("O") + "'");
            break;
    }
}
```